# Skipping overlapping x-axis labels on bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a fairly large data set of years split into two factors, and I want to produce a stacked barplot showing the split between the two factors in each year. I used the following ggplot2 code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=table, aes(x=years, y=Freq, fill=label)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity")+
  labs(x="Hire Year", y="Number of Employees")
```

Which produces this plot

[image]

Due to the large number of bars, the year labels for each bar overlap, so I need a way to only show, say, every 3rd of 4th year, since they're mostly sequential anyway.

Comment: Could you share your data using `dput` or a representative part of it? It would make it easier for someone who wants to help you.

Comment: You could use `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))` to rotate the X-axis labels, as an alternative to omitting some of them.

Comment: Is years a factor - would probably behave better as numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Use major/minor breaks + labels on the x-axis

```
df <- data.frame( x = seq(0,100,1),
                  y = seq(0,100,1) )

ggplot(df, aes( x = x, y = y) ) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(0,100,5), 
                      labels = seq(0, 100, 5), 
                      minor_breaks = seq(0,100,1) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing, you could rotate your axis labels. For example...without rotated x-axis labels...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
ggplot(data=economics, aes(x=year(date), y=unemploy)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity")
```

[plot with horizontal x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AozbM.png)

By adding `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust =1, vjust = 0.5))` to your plot, your x-axis labels would be rotated.

```
ggplot(data=economics, aes(x=year(date), y=unemploy)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust =1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Note that the `vjust` controls the vertical adjustment. 0.5 indicates that we want these labels to be centered.

[plot with rotated x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMTGY.png)